# Fastest way to diagonalize a matrix with a parameter

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I want to diagonalize this matrix $B$ with a parameter $k$:

$$\begin{pmatrix}
5+k & -4-2k & 4+2k & -9-4k \\
2+2k & 1 & 2 & -4-2k \\
7 & -5-2k & 8+2k & -15-3k \\
4 & -4-2k & 4+2k & -8-3k
\end{pmatrix}$$

for all values of $k$. I calculated the characteristic polynomial and found that the spectrum of $B$ is $\{1+k,-k,2,3\}$.

I am perfectly capable of diagonalizing $B$ for every value of $k$, but the struggle is time: there are a lot of matrices that have to be row reduced in order to find a dimension or a basis.

For instance, if $k \in \{1,2,-2,-2\}$, you'll have to rowreduce the eigenspace of resp. eigenvalues $2, 3, 2, 3$ to check multiplicities. I found that $B$ is diagonalizable if $k \in \mathbb{R} \setminus  \{1\}$.

Then, I'll have to row reduce the four eigenspaces again for a $k \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \{2,-2,-3\}$ in order to find a basis for them to write the equation $\Lambda = P^{-1} \cdot B \cdot P$. After that, I have to find a basis of the *odd* eigen space for $k = 2, k=-2,k=-3$ (with the odd eigenspace, I mean the eigenspaces of resp. eigenvalues $2,3,2$, which have a multiplicity $> 1$), in order to find the $P$ matrices and thus the eigenvectors.

In total, there are **12 row reductions** to be done, including matrices with parameters which is an extra struggle. Is there a faster way to achieve the same result with less work?

Comment: Hello Dietrich. At $k=-1/2$, $B$ is diagonalizable since the spectrum will have four different eigenvalues. So no special value there.

Comment: @Moo Yes, that is indeed what I have too. Did you manage to do it with less matrices that you had to row reduce, than 12?

Comment: No, $1+k$ and $-k$ are not different for $k=-1/2$. So the spectrum does not have four different eigenvalues.